# Selenium Webdriver Java: How to get the displayed value from a disabled dropdown list

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to get the displayed value from disabled ddl? Tried the following code:

```
Select select = new Select(Locator);
WebElement option = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
String text= option.getText();
```

Error Displayed: Element should have been select but was input. The element is actually Select but disabled.

DOM:

```
<select class="form-control dirty-checked-field" disabled="disabled" id="Pyear" name="Sections[0].PortfolioYear" title="2019">
```

Comment: Post the html and the locator, you are locating element with `<input>` tag. Notice that the actual dropdown might not have `<select>` tag.

Comment: We can help you only if there is relevant HTML Block.

Comment: Sounds like its not a select element - HTML block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void getList_ByID(String id_element, int list_index_to_click) {
    try {
        WebElement web_el = driver.findElement(By.id(id_element));
        Select select = new Select(web_el);
        List<WebElement> option = select.getOptions();
        option.get(list_index_to_click).getText();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //errors
    }
}
```

Where:

```
id_element is *Pyear*
list_index_to_click is the index of the drop-down list, 

e.g. if your drop-down list has only 1 element then index is 0
```

Others:

1. Try getting the value using xpath
2. Try using attribute= disabled to get the value

Thanks,